# rails seed incorrect column order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-schema

I am attempting to seed a table called countries from a csv file. Other seeds are working in the order I specify, but this one is generating an INSERT statement in alphabetical order that does not map properly to the fields in the csv file. The table countries has a primary key constraint but no sequence or default value. I've called rake db:schema:dump as well in case the schema was out of order with no luck. Any ideas?

**Model**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :abbreviation, :area, :population, :internet_users, :last_updated
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "countries", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                           :null => false
    t.string   "name",           :limit => 50, :null => false
    t.string   "abbreviation",   :limit => 5,  :null => false
    t.integer  "area"
    t.integer  "population"
    t.integer  "internet_users"
    t.datetime "last_updated"
  end
```

**Sample CSV**

```
1,Afghanistan,AF,"645,807","30,419,928","1,520,996",6/12/2013
2,Albania,AL,"28,748","2,986,952","1,441,928",12/11/2013
3,Algeria,DZ,"2,381,741","34,586,184","4,700,000",6/10/2013
4,American Samoa,AS,197,"67,242","3,040",3/11/2013
```

**seeds.rb**

```
@seedfilepath = "#{Rails.root}/db/seedfiles/" 
Country.delete_all
open(@seedfilepath + "countries.csv") do |records|
  records.read.each_line do |record|
    id, name, abbreviation, area, population, internet_users, last_updated = record.chomp.split(',')
    @country = Country.create!(id: id, name: name, abbreviation: abbreviation, area: area, population: population, internet_users: internet_users, last_updated: last_updated)
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(5)
: INSERT INTO "countries" ("abbreviation", "area", "id", "internet_users", "last_updated", "name", "population") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
C:/Users/mmoore/Documents/rubyapps/visitdays/db/seeds.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/mmoore/Documents/rubyapps/visitdays/db/seeds.rb:12:in `each_line'
C:/Users/mmoore/Documents/rubyapps/visitdays/db/seeds.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/mmoore/Documents/rubyapps/visitdays/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you comment out the creation of country objects and check first that the the values you are getting are correct. I used your sample file and ran it with a similar code as yours. There is no error. But since you are getting values in a different order (for example, you may be getting name instead of abbreviation - hence the error). You can even first write a simple ruby script that reads this file and prints the values.
And secondly, you can use [csv module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) which is a standard ruby module for processing data from csv file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue left my machine or rails instance in a terribly bad state. I had to reboot the entire machine, not just the rails server.